# HUE: Выгрузить выборку в файл, минуя браузер

Tags: sql, big-data, hive

В качестве DB использую Impala, в качестве клиента - HUE.

Мне необходимо выгрузить 100кк строк в файл. Как это сделать?

Можно было бы выгрузить сначала в Хью, а потом уже в файл. Но на 100кк оно упадет.

Почему нельзя как в Белке просто сразу поставить вывод на файл?
Или можно? Но как это сделать?

Comment: [так пробовали?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17086642/how-to-export-a-hive-table-into-a-csv-file)

Comment: Спасибо, но это не подходит. Дело в том, что есть Хайв, а есть Импала. Так вот - у нас импала. Так что хайфовые способы не подходят. Спасибо за попытку помочь.

Comment: я надеялся, что в хью есть перенаправления потока вывода, как в белке. Но я так и не нашел. Решил проблему, избежав проблемы: просто сохранил таблицу в текстовом (не паркетном) виде и потом через хдфс взял ее.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так:

```
impala-shell -B -f my-query.sql -o result.csv '--output_delimiter=,'
```